# Common characters in n strings

Tags: java, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

I m trying to make a function that prints the number of characters common in given n strings.   (note that characters may be used multiple times)

I am struggling to perform this operation on n strings However I did it for  2 strings without any characters repeated more than once.

I have posted my code.

```
public class CommonChars {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1 = "abcd";
        String str2 = "bcde";
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        // get unique chars from both the strings

        str1 = uniqueChar(str1);
        str2 = uniqueChar(str2);
        int count = 0;
        int str1Len = str1.length();
        int str2Len = str2.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < str1Len; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < str2Len; j++) {

                // found match stop the loop
                if (str1.charAt(i) == str2.charAt(j)) {
                    count++;
                    sb.append(str1.charAt(i));
                    break;
                }
            }

        }   
        System.out.println("Common Chars Count : " + count + "\nCommon Chars :" + 
        sb.toString());
    }


    public static String uniqueChar(String inputString) {
        String outputstr="",temp="";
        for(int i=0;i<inputstr.length();i++) {
            if(temp.indexOf(inputstr.charAt(i))<0) {
                temp+=inputstr.charAt(i);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("completed");
        return temp;
    }

}
```

```
3 
abcaa
bcbd
bgc
3
```

their may be chances that a same character can be present multiple times in 
 a string and you are not supposed to eliminate those characters instead 
 check the no. of times they are repeated in other strings. for eg

```
 3
 abacd
 aaxyz
 aatre
```

output should be 2

it will be better if i get solution in java

Comment: I already tried the first approach but can you suggest how to  go ahead with your second case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert all `String`s to `Set` of `Character`s and retain all from the first one. Below solution has many places which could be optimised but you should understand general idea.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> input = Arrays.asList("jonas", "ton", "bonny");

        System.out.println(findCommonCharsFor(input));
    }

    public static Collection<Character> findCommonCharsFor(List<String> strings) {
        if (strings == null || strings.isEmpty()) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }

        Set<Character> commonChars = convertStringToSetOfChars(strings.get(0));
        strings.stream().skip(1).forEach(s -> commonChars.retainAll(convertStringToSetOfChars(s)));

        return commonChars;
    }

    private static Set<Character> convertStringToSetOfChars(String string) {
        if (string == null || string.isEmpty()) {
            return Collections.emptySet();
        }

        Set<Character> set = new HashSet<>(string.length() + 10);
        for (char c : string.toCharArray()) {
            set.add(c);
        }

        return set;
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
[n, o]
```

Answer (score 1):

Get list of characters for each string:

```
List<Character> chars1 = s1.chars()    // list of chars for first string
            .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<Character> chars2 = s2.chars()    // list of chars for second string
            .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then use `retainAll` method:

```
chars1.retainAll(chars2);  // retain in chars1 only the chars that are contained in the chars2 also
System.out.println(chars1.size());
```

If you want to get number of unique chars just use `Collectors.toSet()` instead of `toList()`

Answer (score 1):

Well if one goes for hashing:

```
public static int uniqueChars(String first, String second) {
    boolean[] hash = new boolean[26]; 
    int count = 0;
    //reduce first string to unique letters
    for (char c : first.toLowerCase().toCharArray()) {
        hash[c - 'a'] = true;
    }
    //reduce to unique letters in both strings
    for(char c : second.toLowerCase().toCharArray()){
        if(hash[c - 'a']){
            count++; 
            hash[c - 'a'] = false;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

This is using bucketsort which gives a n+m complexity but needs the 26 buckets(the "hash" array). 
Imo one can't do better in regards of complexity as you need to look at every letter at least once which sums up to n+m.

Insitu the best you can get is imho somewhere in the range of O(n log(n) ) .

Your aproach is somewhere in the league of O(n²)

Addon: if you need the characters as a String(in essence the same as above with count is the length of the String returned):

```
public static String uniqueChars(String first, String second) {
    boolean[] hash = new boolean[26]; 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (char c : first.toLowerCase().toCharArray()) {
        hash[c - 'a'] = true;
    }
    for(char c : second.toLowerCase().toCharArray()){
        if(hash[c - 'a']){
            sb.append(c);
            hash[c - 'a'] = false;
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String getCommonCharacters(String... words) {
    if (words == null || words.length == 0)
        return "";

    Set<Character> unique = words[0].chars().mapToObj(ch -> (char)ch).collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));

    for (String word : words)
        unique.retainAll(word.chars().mapToObj(ch -> (char)ch).collect(Collectors.toSet()));

    return unique.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

---

Another variant without creating temporary `Set` and using `Character`.

```
public static String getCommonCharacters(String... words) {
    if (words == null || words.length == 0)
        return "";

    int[] arr = new int[26];
    boolean[] tmp = new boolean[26];

    for (String word : words) {
        Arrays.fill(tmp, false);

        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            int pos = Character.toLowerCase(word.charAt(i)) - 'a';

            if (tmp[pos])
                continue;

            tmp[pos] = true;
            arr[pos]++;
        }
    }

    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(26);

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        if (arr[i] == words.length)
            buf.append((char)('a' + i));

    return buf.toString();
}
```

---

**Demo**

```
System.out.println(getCommonCharacters("abcd", "bcde"));  // bcd
```

Answer (score 0):

A better strategy for your problem is to use this method:

```
public int[] countChars(String s){
    int[] count = new int[26];
    for(char c: s.toCharArray()){
        count[c-'a']++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Now if you have n Strings (String[] strings) just find the min of common chars for each letter:

```
int[][] result = new int[n][26]
for(int i = 0; i<strings.length;i++){
    result[i] = countChars(s);
}
// now if you sum the min common chars for each counter you are ready
int commonChars = 0; 
for(int i = 0; i< 26;i++){
    int min = result[0][i];
    for(int j = 1; j< n;j++){
        if(min>result[j][i]){
            min = result[j][i];
        }
    }
    commonChars+=min;
}
```

Comment: Typo, second index is i, should be j. This would not run.